# Como convertir la hora de unos documentos de formato EDT a GM

Tags: python, visual-studio

soy muy nuevo ocupando python y me pidieron que para la carga masiva de unos documentos Excel se ajuste la hora de formato EDT a formato GM y como tengo muy poca experiencia y lo tengo que terminar lo antes posible pido ayuda de quien sepa, estoy ocupando visual studio code con la herramienta python en su versión 3.9

Anexo parte del código para que se entienda que lo que se quiere lograr

```
#CARGAR DE EXCEL E INSERCION DE LOS DATOS DEL MISMO 
def cargarExcel():
    
    for data in listaIF:
        fechaRecepcion = data[3].to_pydatetime()
        isAnexo = 'true' if  data[7]!="No hay" else 'false'
        props ={'cmis:objectTypeId' : 'D:conList:oficio',
                'cmis:secondaryObjectTypeIds': 'P:sys:localized',
                'dl:dataListItemType':'conList:oficio',
                'conList:estadoOfId':'Aprobado',    
                'conList:estadoResp':'Respondido',  
                #'conList:guidPersonaIF':'',    
                #'conList:tipoDoc':'IF',    
                #'conList:idFirm':'',   
                'conList:quienRecibe':'58b3eac5-6695-41a1-8da1-f3c53f4f3b3b',   
                #'conList:fecVenc':'',  
                #'conList:guidEmisor':'',   
                'conList:ofId':str(data[0]),    
                #'conList:referencia':'',   
                #'conList:guidPadre':'',    
                #'conList:idVeriFirm':'',   
                'conList:anexos':str(data[7]),#EXCEL
                'conList:estadoAnexo': isAnexo,#EXCEL / IF !=NOY RETURN TRUE ELSE FALSE         
                #'conList:fechaEnvio':'',   
                'conList:servicio':str(data[7]),#EXCEL  
                #'conList:estadoFirm':'',   
                #'conList:gerenciaId':'',   
                #'conList:guidAnterior':'', 
                'conList:folio':'0',
                'conList:workflowId':'',     
                'conList:materia':str(data[2]),#EXCEL   
                'conList:guidCarpeta':'',       
                'conList:fecRecepcion':fechaRecepcion,##HORA ESTA EN EDT FALTA CONVERSION A GMT O AGREGAR 4HRS +
                'conList:reqResp':'true'
                }
        nameData = str("IF "+str(data[0]))
        dl_item = dl_folder.createDocument(name=nameData,properties=props)
        print("Exito")

#cargarExcel()
```

Comment: que se supone que contiene `data` y donde esta la fecha?

Comment: Para mejor ayudarte deberías reducir el problema a una planilla simple, con un sólo campo (fecha) a convertir. De ese modo podríamos copiar el código y probar la solución. Así como está, ni modo. Lee [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Estimado el problema es que lo que se quiere lograr es un proyecto de empresa y no te podría facilitar todo el codigo ya que solo soy un practicante y todo el código es para un hospital, y me equivoque no es cambiar la fecha sino la hora para pasar de edt a gm o agregarle 4horas al codigo de fecha

Comment: Podria agregar el codigo como me pides pero no te podria pasar todo el proyecto

Comment: Solo quieres agregarle 4 horas?